# undefined Class method in Ruby (being called before method definition)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid, class-method, bit-fields

I ended up having a very strange error:

When I run this code:

```
class HomeFeature
    include Mongoid::Document
    include Mongoid::Timestamps
    include Mongoid::Bitfield

    belongs_to :home

    def self.amenities
        %w(lobby jacuzzi sauna cinema games roof_garden events_room tennis_court visits_space roaster green_areas cistern)
    end

    bitfield :amenities, *HomeFeature.amenities.map(&:to_sym)
end
```

It works perfectly fine, but this:

```
class HomeFeature
    include Mongoid::Document
    include Mongoid::Timestamps
    include Mongoid::Bitfield

    belongs_to :home

    bitfield :amenities, *HomeFeature.amenities.map(&:to_sym)

    def self.amenities
        %w(lobby jacuzzi sauna cinema games roof_garden events_room tennis_court visits_space roaster green_areas cistern)
    end
end
```

Gives me the error:
```NoMethodError: undefined method `amenities' for HomeFeature:Class````

Can someone please explain why is this happening? Thanks a lot

Comment: The answer is actually already in your question title.

Comment: Yeah but why? This is not how Ruby is supposed to work, doesn't it? It is not like C

Comment: No, it's not "like C", but that doesn't mean that order doesn't matter. Think of it like this: When you define a class, the Ruby interpreter reads through the class, line by line, evaluating code within the context of the class. When it comes across a method definition, it _defines_ the method, but doesn't actually run anything. Order matters.

Comment: The reason that this generally isn't a problem with instance methods, where you can write an instance method that calls another instance method defined somewhere "lower" in the class is that those methods typically _aren't being called at the same time they're being defined_. When you write instance methods like this, the interpreter reads through the class, line-by-line, running class methods and defining new methods. Then, only once the entire class is defined, are objects instantiated from the class. At this point, methods are already defined and methods can call each other just fine.

Answer (score 2):

In the second example, you are trying to call the class method `amenities` before it has been defined (it is called on the line `*HomeFeature.amenities.map(&:to_sym)`, but only defined later). The ordering of the source is important here, as the code is parsed top to bottom.